# Does k way merge sort defies the lower bound for sorting?

Tags: algorithms

Support there is a Array A with size n and let n be a multiple of k. If we divide the A into sub arrays each with elements k and sort them individually, it would require k*log(k) time. Total initial time =(n/k)*k*log(k)=n*log(k). And then merging the sorted sub arrays, let say using a heap of size k will cost atmost n*log(k) time. So total time = 2*n*log(k)+c which is O(n*log(k)). But we know that lower bound for sorting is n*log(n). What is wrong in my thinking?

Comment: $n=ck$, if $c$ is constant the asymptotic rates are the same.

Comment: I think you are mistaken, that merging could be done that fast. You have $\frac{n}{k}$ sorted arrays of size $k$ , so I do not see a way to merge them faster than $O(n log \frac{n}{k})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from merging the arrays.

What I think you're thinking when using a heap is to keep track of the smallest elements from each of the $k$-element sorted arrays, removing the smallest element $s$ them from the heap, putting $s$ in the output, and adding a new element onto the heap from the array which contained $s$.

The problem with this is that there are $n/k$ arrays, so your heap will actually contain $n/k$ elements.

As an extreme case, let $k=1$.  Then your algorithm would consist of sorting each 1-element array (which takes no time) and then merging them using heapsort.